# Comparing Dates In The Same Entry

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am going through a database and am trying to single out entries in a column that do not have the same dates. Most entries in my column `EntryInfo` look like this;

```
| id |   |                        Entry Info                        |
  1       [randomInfo]<datetime1>[randomInfo]<datetime2>[randomInfo]
```

Example:

```
Received: from x400 by nccwh-3.qs-va.comm.net with local (Exim 4.66) (envelope-from <user@comm.net>) id 1aSdvU-0002xZ-3k for SERVER@COMM.COM; Mon, 08 Feb 2016 04:59:52 +0000 X-Virus-Scanned: OK X-Spam-Threshold:95 X-Spam-Score: 0 X-Spam-Flag: NO X-MessageSniffer-Scan-Result: 0 X-MessageSniffer-Rules: 0-0-0-2110-c [some text] Orig-To: SERVER@COMM.COM X-Originating-Ip: [redacted] Date: 08 Feb 2016 04:59:52 +0000 Message-ID:<"15025881 0aa0 56b820c7"* @MHS>..
```

In most cases `<datetime1>` and `<datetime2>` have the same date. However sometimes `DATE(<datetime1>) != DATE(<datetime2>)`. This is what I am looking for. I'm a bit new to using SQL and am unsure on how to check whether or not these dates are the same within the same entry on the table. I believe the entries are just a string.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you share a few sample `EntryInfo` entries so we can figure out how to split the data?

Comment: Hopefully it is readable @SujeetSinha

`..Received: from x400 by nccwh-3.qs-va.comm.net with local (Exim 4.66) (envelope-from <user@comm.net>) id 1aSdvU-0002xZ-3k for SERVER@COMM.COM; **Mon, 08 Feb 2016 04:59:52** +0000 X-Virus-Scanned: OK X-Spam-Threshold:95 X-Spam-Score: 0 X-Spam-Flag: NO X-MessageSniffer-Scan-Result: 0 X-MessageSniffer-Rules: 0-0-0-2110-c [some text] Orig-To: SERVER@COMM.COM X-Originating-Ip: [redacted] Date: **08 Feb 2016 04:59:52** +0000 Message-ID:<"15025881 0aa0 56b820c7"* @MHS>..`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, this is going to get a bit messy -- this assumes all entries are in the same format as the example you posted in the comments.  It boils to down to comparing two substrings of the entry.

Let's start with the code. This will pull all entries where the dates are **different**:

```
SELECT * FROM TestTable
WHERE (SUBSTRING(EntryInfo, PATINDEX('%COMM.COM;%', EntryInfo) + 15, PATINDEX('%+0000%', SUBSTRING(EntryInfo, PATINDEX('%COMM.COM;%', EntryInfo) + 15, PATINDEX('%+0000%', EntryInfo)))-2))
<>(SUBSTRING(EntryInfo, PATINDEX('%Date:%', EntryInfo) + 6, PATINDEX('%+0000%', SUBSTRING(EntryInfo, PATINDEX('%Date:%', EntryInfo) + 6, PATINDEX('%+0000%', EntryInfo)))-1))
```

This compares the two date strings pulled from the entry using [SUBSTRING](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx) AND [PATINDEX](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395(SQL.90).aspx)

SUBSTRING will find a portion of the string. It requires the source string (in the case the column name), a start index (we use PATINDEX for this) and a length.

PATINDEX will return the starting index of a *pattern* you supply it from the source string.

Here we pull the first date string:

```
(SUBSTRING(EntryInfo, PATINDEX('%COMM.COM;%', EntryInfo) + 15, PATINDEX('%+0000%', SUBSTRING(EntryInfo, PATINDEX('%COMM.COM;%', EntryInfo) + 15, PATINDEX('%+0000%', EntryInfo)))-2))
```

Source string is: **EntryInfo**

Starting index is: `PATINDEX('%COMM.COM;%', EntryInfo) + 15`
 -- **Here we are looking for that starting index of the first `COMM.COM;` (and adding 15 to take remove COMM.COM; and day of the week)**

Length is: `PATINDEX('%+0000%', SUBSTRING(EntryInfo, PATINDEX('%COMM.COM;%', EntryInfo) + 15, PATINDEX('%+0000%', EntryInfo)))-2` 
 -- Here were are find the *end* index of the Date by looking for the first index of `+0000` from a string that that *has removed* all the text before the first date. This is the SUBSTRING portion of this. We subtract 2 to remove extra spacing.

Finding the second date using similar logic, but instead uses "Date:" as an indicator for the beginning of the string.

Edit: spelling and minor logic fix.

Updated query to match updated example data.

Comment: Note: The original does not have the double asterisk, it was a formatting error (an attempt to make it bold).

So for the first PATINDEX we could use ('COMM.COM;',.. instead, correct?

Comment: If that is consistent across all your data entries, then yes, you could use that instead. I should be something like `PATINDEX('%COMM.COM;%', EntryInfo) + 15` instead.
I suggest to help you get exactly what you need to just SELECT one date at a time:

Comment: @PaulV Like this `SELECT (SUBSTRING(EntryInfo, PATINDEX('%COMM.COM;%', EntryInfo) + 15, PATINDEX('%+0000%', SUBSTRING(EntryInfo, PATINDEX('%COMM.COM;%', EntryInfo) + 15, PATINDEX('%+0000%', EntryInfo)))-2)) FROM TestTable`
This selects the first date. This way you can see exactly what it is pulling to compare

Comment: @PaulV Updated answer to reflect your data.

Comment: I am now getting an error;

`Msg 537, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.
`

Comment: @PaulV are you using the updated query in the answer, or a different query? If different, please post it and I will take a look.

Comment: @PaulV You could also assume the date length will always be 20. Potentially dangerous, but we're already assuming much in the way your data is laid out. So something like this:
`SELECT * FROM Test
WHERE (SUBSTRING(EntryInfo, PATINDEX('%COMM.COM;%', EntryInfo) + 15, 20))
<>(SUBSTRING(EntryInfo, PATINDEX('%Date:%', EntryInfo) + 6, 20))`

Comment: Thank you! I have to tweak a few values to get exactly what I wanted but it seems to be working now.

Comment: @PaulV You bet! If this solves your problem, please accept my answer as the best answer. Thank you!